# Swift adding multiple images to a single UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

[image]In my app, I would like to add multiple images on a single `UIButton`.

This is what I have now:

```
    NextButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: width*0, y: height*0.55, width: width*0.95, height: height*0.05))
    NextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(OnNextPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    NextButton.isExclusiveTouch = true
    NextButton.setTitle("ButtonText", for: UIControlState())
    NextButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red:0, green:0, blue:0, alpha:1.0), for: UIControlState())
    NextButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "ButtonOutline"), for: .normal)
    view.addSubview(NextButton)
```

I would like a 2nd image as an arrow pointing to the next page.
thanks in advance :)

the rest of the button works but I don't know how to make the arrow appear

Comment: it would be nice if you provide a screen shot of what you have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: 1 sec ill just make a preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem here is the new code:

```
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

    let width = screenSize.width
    let height = screenSize.height

NextButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: width*0, y: height*0.55, width: width*0.95, height: height*0.05))
NextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(OnNextPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
NextButton.isExclusiveTouch = true
NextButton.setTitle("ButtonText", for: UIControlState())
NextButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red:0, green:0, blue:0, alpha:1.0), for: UIControlState())
NextButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "ButtonOutline"), for: .normal)
NextButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow_next"), for: UIControlState())
NextButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, width*0.7)
view.addSubview(NextButton)
```

by simply adding setImage to the code i could create a second image on top of the BackgroundImage. then by suing imageEdgeInsets i aligned the image on the button.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve and how this answer solves your problem. Otherwise it will be of no value to future visitors. Thank you.

Comment: added an explanation is it clear like this or do i need or add something else?