# Xamarin.Forms - iOS - Custom effect to place multiple images on UIButton

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uibutton, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms (Portable project) with custom effects and I am trying to achieve the following layout of a button on iOS:

```
___________________________________
|                                  |
||image2|    'Button 1'    |image2||
|__________________________________|
```

In Android it is achievable by using `button.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom)`. Where the parameters are the appropriate Android drawables.

Right now I am using subviews added to the UIButton but I'm struggling to achieve the above behaviour.

`button.AddSubView(leftImage);
 button.AddSubView(rightImage);`

Any ideas?

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39979091/3901620

Comment: I think is good approach. When u create e.g leftImage define his rectangle and add it as subview like in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple `UIImageView`s and slice your `UIButton` layout into whatever partitions you need for your images and text, here is one in thirds:

```
public override void LayoutSubviews()
{
    var image1 = new UIImageView(new UIImage("btn_image.png"))
    {
        Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, Frame.Width / 3, Frame.Height)
    };
    Add(image1);
    var image2 = new UIImageView(new UIImage("btn_image.png"))
    {
        Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect((Frame.Width / 3) * 2, 0, Frame.Width / 3, Frame.Height)
    };
    Add(image2);
    base.LayoutSubviews();
}
```

Comment: Would this require sub-classing `UIButton`?

Comment: You should be able to do it with an effect, but I greatly prefer custom renderers

Comment: I agree, however, I chose effects as I did not need the full flexibility of custom renderers.

Regarding your answer, I can sub-class UIButton and cast the targeted 
native control to my custom button. Is there a need to override `LayoutSubviews()`? I can just as well create my own function that does the above. Or, is it best-practice to do so?

Comment: @Ethan When `LayoutSubviews` is called from its `UIView`, the view's bounds will be correct. You should cache the `UIImageView`s that you need to create and (re)position them everytime LayoutSubviews gets called (scrolling, rotations, etc... ), Otherwise you would need to monitor calls to `SetNeedsLayout` and fire your custom method...